# Xcode Image Literal

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I am new at Swift and Xcode. Image literals not seem as a picture.

I want to make an array of Image Literals. I want them look like a small picture in code not a string. Like at the screenshoot.[I want to see the images like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPvHy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding `#` before image literal, for example:

`#imageLiteral(resourceName: "some-image")`